# 5/12 Roof Pitch - Loft Options

Tags: roof, attic

24x24 16'Ht Garage with a 12x24 Loft

Intent: conversion to an off grid home.
Could I lower 1st floor rooms under loft area from 10' a 7' ceiling height to create enough room in the loft area to have a decent sized bedroom?

live in central pennsylvania

thanks

Comment: Yes, maybe, no.  Pictures showing the attic construction will help.  Good chance you will have to build a floor for the loft instead of just dropping the ceiling.  Depending on construction might need to build a second floor and adding a roof.

Comment: If that's a garage built with a "spare room truss" for the roof area, (what it sounds like based on the dimensions) the roof will fall down if you cut away the truss bottom chords (the present floor framing of the loft area.) Reframing to accomplish what you want is probably more expensive than building a whole new structure as an addition. And will likely need an engineer.

Comment: eewww ok - that makes sense.  thank you!

Comment: make an answer out of that, @Ecnerwal

Comment: 7 ft ceilings will likely make your home un-sellable, and building a new roof might be a similar cost and effort to removing and replacing a ceiling.  Then there is the issue of if the roof will stay up without ceiling joists.

Comment: The International Residential Code specifies 7'-0" as the minimum height for habitable space (living, sleeping, eating, cooking). If you go with 7'-0", then build to 7'-0" (framing at 7' - 0-1/2"), not 6' - 11-3/4".

Answer (score 0):

If that's a garage built with a "spare room truss" for the roof area, (what it sounds like based on the dimensions) the roof will fall down if you cut away the truss bottom chords (the present floor framing of the loft area.)

Reframing to accomplish what you want is probably more expensive than building a whole new structure as an addition. And doing so will likely need an engineer.

I'd just plan on building the addition (though I might also plan on doing so when and as funds permit if I could *make do* until then.)